# Not enough RAM to run stargazer the normal way

Tags: r, stargazer

The table data1 has around 350k observations. I would like to estimate the 6 models below and output the results in latex using stargazer.I should specify that y1 is a binary variable and I'm dealing with 100 firms. I'm afraid I don't have any data to post.

Here is my code. The problem is that each estimation is stored in the RAM and there are not enough memory left to run Stargazer.

**I'll have two questions?**

1. Is there a way to store the `glm' objects on the disk and then call them back with stargazer?
2. Does stargazer need the whole 'glm' object to output the latex code.?

   l0 <- glm(y1~ x1 + log(x2)+ x3+ 
                   factor(x5)+ factor(firms) ,data=data1, family=binomial(link=logit), model=FALSE)

   ```
   l1 <- glm(y1~ x1 + log(x2)+ x3+
               factor(x5)+  x4+factor(firms) ,data = data1,family=binomial(link=logit), model=FALSE)

   l2 <- glm(y1~x1 +log(x2)+  x3+ 
               factor(x5)+x4+ factor(x6) + factor(firms), data=data1,family=binomial(link=logit)
             , model=FALSE)

   l3 <- glm(y1~x1 +log(x2) + x3+
               factor(x5) + x4+factor(x6)   + x7+ factor(firms)
            ,data = data1,family=binomial(link=logit), model=FALSE)

   l4 <- glm(y1~x1 + log(x2) + x3+ 
               factor(x5) +x4+ factor(x6)+ x7+installments + 
               factor(firms) ,data = data1,family=binomial(link=logit), model=FALSE)

   l5 <- glm(y1~x1 + log(x2) + x3+ 
               factor(x5) +x4+ factor(x6)+ x7 +installments + x8+
               factor(firms) ,data = data1,family=binomial(link=logit), model=FALSE)


   stargazer(l0,l1,l2,l3,l4,title="Regression Results with Fixed Effects",     align=TRUE,apply.coef=or
         ,out = "path.tex", covariate.labels=covlabel,omit="firms",
         omit.labels="Firms", omit.yes.no=c("Yes","No"))
   ```

Comment: This is currently to vague... no data, no code, no description of the task. You should edit to fix these defects or it may get closed.

Comment: Thanks for the commment. I've updated the my question trying to be more specific. Please free to make any suggestions

Comment: Regarding your second question, it looks like the answer here will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010742/using-stargazer-with-memory-greedy-glm-objects

Comment: As a temporary measure, I added support for speedglm (logistic regressions *only*) to stargazer.  You can download it from my GitHub account at https://github.com/jcfisher/stargazer (or use `devtools::install_github("jcfisher/stargazer")`).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using [texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/index.html) now as it is more flexible. A solution would be to take what you need from the glm object and create another object, say myglm. then create a function to extract the information from myglm. I would suggest having a look at [this doc](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v055i08) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098295/combining-two-tables-and-adding-a-header-for-each-table-in-r/24193452#24193452)

Answer (score 1):

My approach when faced with this problem is to first convert the *lm object to a "coeftest" class using the `lmtest` package. For more details, see my answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010742/using-stargazer-with-memory-greedy-glm-objects/40029509#40029509).

Answer (score 0):

As per [stargazer manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf), it does not support the packages you mention at the time of this writing. As for other options, I would first try running the analysis with the stock `lm()`. If it does not lead to RAM-related problems, you'll have a choice to make between the speed of estimation and the ease of formatting your table.

You might also choose to contact the developer, asking to add `bigglm` and `speedglm` to the feature wish list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I need to estimate a non linear model so  as far as I understand, lm cannot do the job. I'll try the wish list.

Comment: @DJJ this depends on what you mean by "non-linear". If you mean polynomials (quadratic, cubic terms etc), then lm() will do the job just fine; see poly() function.

Comment: I was thinking more of a logistic estimation.