# Using stargazer with memory greedy glm objects

Tags: r, glm, stargazer

I'm trying to run the following regression:

```
m1=glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=df,family=binomial())
m2=glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5,data=df,family=binomial())
m3=glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6,data=df,family=binomial())
m4=glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7,data=df,family=binomial())
```

and then to print them using the *stargazer* package:

```
stargazer(m1,m2,m3,m4 type="html", out="models.html")
```

Thing is, the data frame df is rather big (~600MB) and thus each glm object I create is at least ~1.5GB.
This creates a memory issue which prevents me from creating all the regressions I need to print in *stargazer*.

I've tried 2 approches in order to decrease the size of the glm objects:

1. Trim the glm object using [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/) tutorial. This indeed trims the glm object to <1MB, though I get the following error from the stargazer function:

```html
Error in Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

2. Use the package *speedglm*. however, it's not supported by *stargazer*.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a temporary measure, I added support for speedglm (logistic regressions *only*) to stargazer.  You can download it from my GitHub account at https://github.com/jcfisher/stargazer (or use `devtools::install_github("jcfisher/stargazer")`).

Comment: Thanks you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

An option that has worked well for me is to first convert the large *lm objects to "coeftest" class using the `lmtest` package. A "coeftest" object is really just a matrix of your summarised regression results and hardly takes up any space as a result. Moreover, Stargazer readily accepts the "coeftest" class as an input, so your code doesn't need to change much at all.

Using your example:

```
library(lmtest)

m1 <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=df,family=binomial())
m1 <- coeftest(m1)
m2 <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5,data=df,family=binomial())
m2 <- coeftest(m2)
m3 <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6,data=df,family=binomial())
m3 <- coeftest(m3)
m4 <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7,data=df,family=binomial())
m4 <- coeftest(m4)

stargazer(m1,m2,m3,m4 type="html", out="models.html")
```

Apart from taking care of the memory problem, this approach has the added benefit of the `coeftest()` transformation itself being extremely quick. (Well, with the notable exception of times when you ask it to produce robust/clustered standard errors on a particularly large *lm object by invoking the "vcov = vcovHC" option. However, even then, the `coeftest()` transformation is a necessary step to exporting the robust regression results in the first place.)

A minor downside to this approach is that it doesn't save some regression statistics that may be of interest for your Stargazer table (e.g. R-squared or N). However, you could easily obtain these from the *lm object before converting it.

Answer (score 2):

The `stargazer` calls `summary` which requires `qr` (see source code). So -- as far as I know -- it is not possible.

BUT I think that it should be easy to rewrite stargazer to handle a list of summaries as an input. It would be extremely handy.